# Remove Blank from a Calculated Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns, nonblank

I have a query in Power BI which is taking all the unique values from 6 different Table's columns and creating a New Table.

> Query -

```
All Country = 
VAR newTable = 
UNION (
    SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Country]),
    SUMMARIZE(Table2, Table2[New country]),
    SUMMARIZE(Table3, Table1[Countrys]),
    SUMMARIZE(Table4, Table2[New country Name]),
    SUMMARIZE(Table5, Table1[country]),
    SUMMARIZE(Table6, Table2[new country])
)

RETURN 
    (SUMMARIZE(Table1, Table1[Country]))
```

Now When I do that I find out there are Empty Values in the New table. Now to remove that I tried many different ways the `<>BLANK()` Function. But somehow it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any Idea how to remove the Blank from this Calculated Table!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this might work:

RETURN

filter(newTable,Table1[Country]<>blank())
?